# Back Projection using openCV for python

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

I am using openCV for Python, the cv2 library. I use the following function to compute the histogram of an image im_converted

```
hist = cv2.calcHist([im_converted], channels, None, histSize, ranges,hist, 1)
```

where im_converted is loaded as a numpy array of type uint8.

hist seems to be forced to be a numpy array of type float32. A problem arises when I use the backprojection function. (note: I normalize the histogram s.t np.sum(hist)=1)

```
backProj = cv2.calcBackProject([im_converted], channels, hist, ranges,scale);
```

The documentation is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calcbackproject#cv2.calcBackProject). backProj is forced to be an uint8 numpy array.

- if scale=1, then backProj = 0
- if scale=255 then backProj is non zero, but the values are very small.

My question is: what is the scale factor that should be applied, given the differences between the types? Isn't there a way of changing the types? (note: I tried to do hist=zeros(histSize, dtype=uint8) but this was unsuccessful, I still got a float32 histogram in the end.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your image size.  If your image has more than 255 pixels, then a uint8 datatype for your histogram is not sufficient because the bins may oveflow.

It seems line OpenCV forces the datatype of the returned image from `calcBackProject` to be the same as image passed in.  If you pass in a `uint8` image but your `float32` histogram has values larger than 255 your backprojection image may be clipped.

The most sane way of doing this appears to be keep the scale = 1.0 but pass in a `float32` image to `calcBackProject`:

`backProj = cv2.calcBackProject([im_converted.astype('float32')], channels, hist, ranges,scale)`

The other alternative is to pass in `uint8` image but set the scale to be `255. / hist.max()`.  Thus 255 in your backprojected image will correspond to the most frequent color.